# Failed to load image to texture vector (SFML)

Tags: c++, image, vector, textures, sfml

We are trying to load textures to a vector of textures in order to be able building a game.
The program is thrown once getting to the line where we are trying to load the image to the vector.
The vector's definition is:

vector> m_textureVec;

```
#include "Resources.h"
#include <thread>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using std::vector;

Resources Resources::m_instance = Resources();

Resources::Resources()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<sf::Texture>> m_textureVec;
    m_textureVec.resize(8);

    m_textureVec[0]->loadFromFile("digger.png");
    m_textureVec[1]->loadFromFile("monster.png");
    m_textureVec[2]->loadFromFile("diamond.png");
    m_textureVec[3]->loadFromFile("present.png");
    m_textureVec[4]->loadFromFile("stone.png");
    m_textureVec[5]->loadFromFile("wall.png");
    m_textureVec[6]->loadFromFile("background.png");
    m_textureVec[7]->loadFromFile("empty.png");
}
```

Comment: The problem is the resizeing the problem is that the cell of the vec that we are tryied to input to a cell its crashed

Comment: Sorry I have mistaken vector methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the `unique_ptr` to hold. Right now you have 8 `unique_ptr`s with nothing to point to.

```
Resources::Resources()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<sf::Texture>> m_textureVec;
    m_textureVec.resize(8);

    m_textureVec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>(new sf::Texture()));
    m_textureVec[0]->loadFromFile("digger.png");
    //etc
}
```

Also, you will lose your `m_textureVec` when your `Resources()` function finishes. It's best to create that variable in a more long-lasting environment.

Comment: But now i got error "no operator "=" matches these operands"

Comment: @OrtalYatzkan See my changes, sorry. I forgot that you have to assign it to another `unique_ptr`, not a raw one.

Comment: @OrtalYatzkan I made a pretty rookie mistake, you need to use `push_back()`. Check the answer again. Maybe just use an array if you know the size of the vector, it'd be simpler to work with.

Comment: now the error is :"unique_ptr has no member push_back"

Comment: @OrtalYatzkan Do `m_textureVec.push_back`, not `m_textureVec[0].push_back`

Comment: now i got error"Access violation writing location " again

Comment: do you know what does the function "reset" does?

Comment: Yeah, it's [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset). It's a member function of `unique_ptr`, not `sf::Texture`

Comment: Are you able to debug? Try debugging and seeing where the error is being thrown. That should help you to find out why it cannot access `m_textureVec[0]`.

Comment: yes, i do and i see that its thrown in line: " m_textureVec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>(new sf::Texture()));
"